# Joining one of two fields in a dbf table to a single ArcGIS shapefile field - Python

Tags: join, dbf, arcpy

I have a table that I would like to join to an ArcGIS shapefile. My problem is that the table has two Identity fields (i.e. "Plan Number" and "Contract Number") and the shapefile has one Identity field (i.e. "Name"). I want to join the shapefile's "Name" to either the "Plan Number" OR the "Contract Number".

As background, the shapefile is created by manually drawing in polygons in ArcGIS. These polygons represent various projects. The identifier "Name" can either be a project's initial Planning Number, or the Contract Number that exists after the project is budgeted. The Planning Number exists when there is no budget, and the Contract Number comes later. Polygons are created and the "Name" field is filled in with whichever identifying stage (either Planning Number or Contract Number) the project has reached. So, the shapefile field "Name" contains either Planning Numbers or Contract Numbers.

Concurrently, we have a complex Database of all projects with two fields representing both the Planning Number and Contract Number:

PLN------------Contract-----Phase------------Length-----NTP---------SC-------------Notes

1415-003-----WD-2506----Pre-Planning----45----------1/1/1900----1/20/1900-----test

To create my code, I created a simple xml table that links to the Database. This xml table has a PLN (Plan Number) field and a Contract (Contract Number) field. In my code, I converted this xml to a dbf. I am now trying to find a way to join a Shapefile "Name" to EITHER the "PLN" or the "Contract".

Please see code below:

```
#Convert xlsx to table:
import xlrd

in_excel= r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\JoinTest.xlsx'
out_table= r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\JoinTest.gdb'


# Perform the conversion
join_table= arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(in_excel, out_table)

print join_table

# Join
# Set the local parameters
inFeatures = r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\CDDprojects.shp'
joinField = 
joinTable = join_table
fieldList = ["PLN", "Contract", "Phase", "Length", "NTP", "SC", "Notes]
```

I am unsure what to enter in joinField and if there is any other code I should include.

REVISION 1: 
I used Ethan's code but received an error message at:

```
with master_table.open():
    with minimal_table.open():
        minimal_index = dbf.create_index(minimal_table, lambda record: record.name)
```

The error reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Engineering\ENGINEER\LAMP (062012)\Database\VisualDatabase\LAMP.py", line 53, in <module>
    with master_table.open():
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'open'
```

REVISION 2:
I am a beginner level so perhaps I am missing something fairly simple. When I try to import dbf, I am receiving the an error after my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Engineering\ENGINEER\LAMP (062012)\Database\VisualDatabase\LAMP.py", line 50, in <module>
    import dbf
ImportError: No module named dbf
```

I downloaded the dbf module, but when running the setup, I receive this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 267
    warnings.warn(msg)
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to install the dbf.

REVISION 3: 
I have installed the dbf module and it is successfully imported into arcpy. However, I am still receiving the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Engineering\ENGINEER\LAMP (062012)\Database\VisualDatabase\LAMP.py", line 56, in <module>
    with master_table.open():
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'open'
```

My code is:

```
#Convert xlsx to table:
import xlrd

in_excel= r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\JoinTest.xlsx'
out_table= r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\JoinTest.gdb'

# Perform the conversion
join_table= arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(in_excel, out_table)

import enum
import dbf

# table with all projects at all stages
master_table = join_table
# table with single project and most up-to-date stage
minimal_table = r'W:\\Engineering\\ENGINEER\\LAMP (062012)\\Database\\VisualDatabase\\Planning_Out\\CDDprojects.dbf'

with master_table.open():    (LINE 56 which the AttributeError calls)
    with minimal_table.open():
        minimal_index = dbf.create_index(minimal_table, lambda record: record.name)

# cycle through master, updating minimal if necessary
        for master in master_table:
 # look for PLN # first
            found = minimal_index.search(master.PLN)
            if not found:
                # if record doesn't exist with PLN #, try CONTRACT #
                found = minimal_index.search(master.Contract)
```

I am using the dbf module here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf

Thanks.

Comment: The `AttributeError` is referencing a `'Result' object` -- There are no such things in my `dbf` package -- is there some other `dbf` that is being used instead of mine?

Comment: You are correct. However, I am having problems with the "import dbf" command. Please see revised question.

Comment: @Ethan  After importing dbf, I am still receiving the same AttributeError that references a 'Result' object. I import xlrd to convert my excel sheet to a dbf table... could xlrd be in conflict with the dbf module?

Comment: You'll need to find out what a `Result` object is.  after you get your `join_table` try doing a `print(join_table)` and a `print(dir(join_table))` -- that should give you some clues as to what you can do with that object

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with arcpy (and I'm not entirely certain I understand what you are trying to do), but using [my `dbf` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) this is what you do to update/add from the master table to the shape table's dbf file:

```
import dbf

# table with all projects at all stages
master_table = dbf.Table(complex_table)
# table with single project and most up-to-date stage
minimal_table = dbf.Table(single_project_table)

with master_table.open():
    with minimal_table.open():
        minimal_index = dbf.create_index(minimal_table, lambda record: record.name)

        # cycle through master, updating minimal if necessary
        for master in master_table:
            # look for PLN # first
            found = minimal_index.search(master.pln)
            if not found:
                # if record doesn't exist with PLN #, try CONTRACT #
                found = minimal_index.search(master.contract)
                if not found:
                    # not there at all, add it
                    minimal_table.append(master.contract or master.pln, master.phase, master.length, ...)
                    break

            # have a match, update it
            found.name = master.contract or master.pln
            # plus any other updates you need
            # ...
            # and then write the record
            dbf.write(found)
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Please see revised question with error message.